# android datepicker without datepicker dialog

Tags: android, android-widget

I am currently trying to display a date(in the text format) selected using a "datepicker" on a textview, I want to update the textview as and when the date in the date picker is changed and I want to display the date in the long format ( eg. January 1 2011)

I tried looking up examples but the examples use the date picker dialog. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I found that the Calendar.getDisplayName() returns the string value..but I'm still trying to figure out how to use the datepicker without the dialog

Comment: Found out that you can use  onTimeChangedListener and onDateChangedListener for this....thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used onTimeChangedListener and onDateChangedListener for this..works!

Answer (score 0):

Use getDayofMonth(), getMonth(), and getYear(), you can get the day, month and year set by user, then you can user switch statement to convert integer month to corresponding month. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes..but I also do not want to use the date picker dialog..instead I just want to change the date in the date picker and I want that change to be reflected on a textview

Answer (score -1):

hey i think you should look at this [date picker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html)

it is helpful

Comment: Yes I did look at that before posting this question...but I dont want to use the datepicker dialog